# Trying to pass a UIElement as a parameter in a function

Tags: swift

I would like to pass a UIElement as a parameter of a function in Swift. Basically I would not like to have to repeat myself over and over again for different elements in some child VC's so I am looking for a handy function which looks neater. I am adding accessibility to my app and would like to have a function which sets its identifier and label in a handy function, please see below.

This is currently what I have, I would like a generic UIElement parameter instead of the current UITextField that I currently have so I can also use the function on other elements such as UIButtons etc.

```
let textFieldEdit = "Text Field. double tap to edit."

        nvc.firstNameTextField.isAccessibilityElement = true
        nvc.firstNameTextField.accessibilityIdentifier = "First name"
        nvc.firstNameTextField.accessibilityLabel = "First name \(textFieldEdit)"
```

But I would really like something like the following....

```
func accessibilityElement(name:String, vc:UIViewController, element:UITextField) {
        let textFieldEdit = "Text Field. double tap to edit."

        vc.element.isAccessibilityElement = true
        vc.element.accessibilityIdentifier = name
        vc.element.accessibilityLabel = "\(name) \(textFieldEdit)"
    }
```

I am currently receiving the error below for each line in the function.

> Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'element'; did you mean
>   'present'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the function as follow for `UITextField`

```
func accessibilityElement(name: String, element: UITextField) {
    let textFieldEdit = "Text Field. double tap to edit."

    element.isAccessibilityElement = true
    element.accessibilityIdentifier = name
    element.accessibilityLabel = "\(name) \(textFieldEdit)"
}
```

You can **generalize** it for any `UIView` so it works for other elements such as `UIButton`

```
func accessibilityElement(name: String, element: UIView) {
    let textFieldEdit = "Text Field. double tap to edit."

    element.isAccessibilityElement = true
    element.accessibilityIdentifier = name
    element.accessibilityLabel = "\(name) \(textFieldEdit)"
}
```

You can also write it as `extension` for `UIView`

```
extension UIView {
    func setAccessibility(name: String) {
        let textFieldEdit = "Text Field. double tap to edit."

        isAccessibilityElement = true
        accessibilityIdentifier = name
        accessibilityLabel = "\(name) \(textFieldEdit)"
    }
}
```

Then you can call that:

```
textField.setAccessibility(name: "someTextField") 
button.setAccessibility(name: "someButton")`
```

Comment: Thanks ended up using the second one. :)

Comment: @rb2030 I would prefer to use the third one, Anyway you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Why you passing the viewCOntroller object to the method. just create a method and pass your UI element to it. 
i created a `NSObject` Class and method inside it to handle this thing

```
  class accessibilityHelper : NSObject {
        class func accessibilityElement(name:String, element:UIView) {
            let textFieldEdit = "Text Field. double tap to edit."

            element.isAccessibilityElement = true
            element.accessibilityIdentifier = name
            element.accessibilityLabel = "\(name) \(textFieldEdit)"
        }
    }
```

and use like this

```
accessibilityHelper.accessibilityElement(name: "My TextFiled", element: textField)
```

by using this you can set accessibility property to any textfield of any viewController